# Flex-box only display as many items that fit in a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to only use CSS to make it so I have a container which is using `display: inline-flex`. I want this container to only display internal items if they fit within the container and do not overflow. If any part of the container inside overflows, then I do not want to display it. Currently I can hide the portion of the box that overflows, but i can't hide the whole overflowed item.

Is there any way to accomplish with just HTML and CSS? What I have currently working is in this code snippet https://codepen.io/duebstep/pen/OXENqN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I added a fixed height to the `flex-container` and set the `flex-wrap` to `wrap`
(and changed the `nowrap` rule to `wrap`)

```css
.flex-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 130px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.wrap  { 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes it is, Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: I need to determine the number of items that are currently being shown. Is this possible?

Comment: @SamuelNoyes -- Not with CSS, you will need a script. The script could e.g. look for each child items top value, and for the one's that is less than the parent containers _height_, are visible.

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
<ul class="flex-container nowrap">
 <li class="flex-item">1</li>
 <li class="flex-item">2</li>
 <li class="flex-item">3</li>
 <li class="flex-item">4</li>
 <li class="flex-item">5</li>
 <li class="flex-item">6</li>
 <li class="flex-item">7</li>
 <li class="flex-item">8</li>
 <li style="clear:both"></li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
<style>
 .flex-container {
   max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;

}

.flex-item {
  float:left;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;

  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts.  First, to detect of a div partially sits outside of it's parent is a javascript trick, not css.

Second, read [this awesome guide to flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).  It will help you clean up your css and make a few things much cleaner for you.  It certainly helped me.

Finally, It might be possible with css depending on the fixed sizing your using.  Are you going to allow scrolling? why are their hard heights, and min-widths?  This may help me guide you to a more tailored solution.