# React: Only display items which fully fit within flex box, and dynamically determine the number of items being displayed

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38599445/2142112) is very very close to being what I want. I have a vertical flexbox with items that have a fixed height. I would like as many items as possible to be displayed, but if an item overflows at all, it should be completely omitted. Try the code snippet in the linked answer to see what I mean. This effect can pretty easily be achieved by setting 'flex-wrap: wrap' and overflow hidden on the container.

However, I have one more issue: instead of just displaying these items, I also need to know HOW MANY are currently being displayed. I'm trying to show as many items as will fit, and then at the bottom a label will say "...and 5 more" if there are five items that don't fit, for example. What's the easiest way to go about this? I would love to avoid just dividing the height of the container by the heights of the individual items if possible. There must be a better way.

Comment: I doubt there is a better way. There is nothing that can give you this information in the child component. Calculating how many items fit inside the parent isn't something bad, this is how javascript works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did a lot of digging and finally came to a solution that I'm happy with. Use `offsetLeft` of the elements in order to determine which ones are wrapped. Do the same but with `offsetTop` for a horizontal flex box.

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

React:

```
const items = [...]; // Array of ReactElements

const [numberOfItemsDisplayed, setNumberOfItemsDisplayed] = useState(0);
const ref = useRef(null)

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const cells = ref.current?.children;
    if (cells && cells.length > 0) {
        const startingOffset = cells[0].offsetLeft;
        let numItems = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            if (cells[i].offsetLeft > startingOffset) {
                break;
            }
            numItems++;
        }
        setNumberOfItemsDisplayed(numItems);
    }
}, []);

return <div class="container" ref={ref}>{items}</div>
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! One small comment for anyone who may see this post in the future, there is a minor typo in the nested if which should instead be:
if (cells[i].offsetLeft > startingOffset) { break; }